# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.datasets' when importing tensorflow.keras.datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm receving a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.datasets'` error when running this code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
```

I have `tensorflow version 2.2.0` installed and `keras 2.2.4` installed so I'm not sure why I'm receiving this particular error.

Shoudn't the tensorflow module encapsulate `datasets`?

Comment: Do you have a file called tensorflow.py ?

Comment: does ```import tensorflow as tf``` work? -asking this to determine if it is a problem with tensorflow the package or just importing the dataset

Comment: wouldn't `tf.keras.datasets.cifar10` is imported already when you import `tensorflow`?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy when I run ```mdfind``` in my terminal, it outputs ```/Users/Shared/Relocated Items/Security/anaconda3/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.13.1-mkl_py37h66b1bf0_0/info/files```

Comment: @IvanWiryadi That is what I thought

Comment: @griffin_cosgrove Yes, when I ```import tensorflow as tf``` and ```print(tf.__version__)``` it prints version 2.2.0 –

Comment: have you tried ```from keras.datasets import cifar10``` ?

Answer (score 3):

the [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/cifar10/load_data) has this method listed as the way to load the dataset `tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()`